# Separate notification icon in Unity Android project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have added an Icon in my Unity Project and built it for Android. However, my Icon is in "Apple style" meaning that its a square with rounded corners and graphics inside. This results in the Notification Icon shown in the statusbar is just a white square with rounded corners. I would like to replace this white square icon with another piece of graphic.

How do I do that in Unity?

Ideally I would not have to buy or integrate a thirdparty plugin since they most likely will contain a lot of features that would bloat my project unnecessarily. But, if there is a thirdparty plugin that solves this it would be interesting to know too, so that I could learn how they solved it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the icon is managed in the Player Settings section in Unity. If your icon has rounded corners that's because you made the icon with rounded corners.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, that is what I did to add my app Icon that I want displayed in the Launcher. However, in the Statusbar I want a seperate Icon, much like Snapchat, Whatsapp and Facebook does.

Comment: Ah. I haven't mad with those...so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Place a small simplified version of your icon in a plugins folder either like this "Plugins/Android/**res/drawable**/small_icon.png" or "Plugins/Android/MyProjectPlugin/**res/drawable**/small_icon.png"

The important bit is to send the id "small_icon" in push notification message body, see [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

```
{
    "to" : "...",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "a body",
        "title" : "a title",
        "icon" : "small_icon"
    }
}
```

It's well documented in the [Prime31 Cloud Messaging Plugin documentation](https://prime31.com/docs#androidGoogleCloudMessaging):

> Both the smallIcon and largeIcon will be loaded via the standard
>   Android resources system. That means the icon files must be located in
>   the res/drawable folder. You must reference them using the standard
>   Android naming system. As an example, if you place the files
>   small_icon.png and large_icon.png in the Plugins/Android/res/drawable
>   folder you would want to pass "small_icon" and "large_icon" with the
>   push notification. For all icon size details visit the Android
>   documentation.

Firebase Cloud Messaging describes how to setup your [AndroidManifest.xml](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

```
 <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
     notification message. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```